AzureFileCopy@6 - AzureInvalid Auto-login type specified
I am using AzureFileCopy@6 to copy files to Azure Blob Storage, but I'm encountering an error: "Invalid Auto-login type specified."
"Allow storage account key access" is disabled, and "Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal" is enabled. I've granted the service principal the Storage Blob Data Contributor role.
- task: AzureFileCopy@6
    displayName: 'Configs Files Copy'
          inputs:
            SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.DefinitionName)/ConfigurationFiles/ApplicationService/BlobStorageFiles/ConfigsFiles'
            azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription1'
            Destination: AzureBlob
            storage: 'storage1'
            ContainerName: configsfiles
          continueOnError: true

Screenshot


AzureFileCopy@6 - AzureInvalid Auto-login type specified

The above error occured may be authentication type you specified for the AzureFileCopy task is not valid. The AzureFileCopy@6 task supports Workload Identity Federation and uses Azure RBAC to access Azure Storage.
In my environment, created service connection added the  Storage blob data contributor role to access the blob storage.
Portal:


Now, using the below yaml script it is copied successfully from source path to destination path.
Script:.
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@6
  inputs:
    SourcePath: 'sample.txt'
    azureSubscription: '<your service connection name>'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'venkat789'
    ContainerName: 'test'
displayName: AzureFileCopy

Reference:

AzureFileCopy@6 - Azure file copy v6 task | Microsoft Learn

Azure DevOps Pipeline Azure File Copy Failing by wenbo


